# Images inside flatlist flickering when other hook is updated

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a react native app that handles messages, but when i post a image and then update a hook that isn't even connected to the flatlist the images is still flickering.

[image]

Data structure used

```js
const messages: Message = {
  avatar: 'https://pingopongblog.files.wordpress.com/2015/11/stefan.jpg',
  from: 'Stefan Löfven',
  conversationId: 0,
  message: [
    {
      messageId: 5,
      message: "of letters, as opposed to using 'Content",
      timeStamp: new Date(),
      sentFromMe: true
    },
    ...
  ]
};
```

This is my code for the flatlist and the input

```js
const [test, setTest] = useState('');

const MessageBubble = (props: { message: MessageInfo }) => {
  if (props.message.sentFromMe)
    return <RightMessage message={props.message} />;
  return (
    <LeftMessage
      message={props.message}
      from={messages.from}
      avatar={messages.avatar}
    />
  );
};

.........

<View style={styles.container}>
  <FlatList
    data={messages.message}
    renderItem={({ item }) => <MessageBubble message={item} />}
    keyExtractor={item => item.messageId.toString()}
    scrollEventThrottle={1}
    inverted={true}
  />
</View>
<Input
  value={test}
  onChangeText={e => setTest(e)}
/>
```

Message bubble RightMessage Component

```js
export default (props: { message: MessageInfo }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.messageContainerRight}>
      {props.message.image && (
        <Image
          style={{
            borderRadius: 15,
            height: props.message.image.height / 10,
            width: props.message.image.width / 10
          }}
          resizeMode='contain'
          source={{ uri: props.message.image.uri }}
        />
      )}
      {!props.message.image && (
        <View style={styles.messageHolderRight}>
          <Text style={styles.messageTextRight}>
            {props.message.message}
          </Text>
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};
```

I get that this can occure when the `keyExtractor` is updated, but I have same unique values that stay the same untill a post is done, and I can't find anything wrong with it.

How can I stop this flickering from happening?

Comment: If u provide code where message renders it will be easier. 
Problem might be here `renderItem={({ item }) => <MessageBubble message={item} />}` as it creates a new function every time you component updates. Make a simple render function which renders a message and wrap it with useCallback

Comment: @poltorin how would i use useCallback? I dont see it changing anything, but i may be wrong

Comment: try to add `key={message.messageId}` prop to message component to prevent rerendering

Comment: @poltorin I tried that already, had no effect sadly

Answer (score 0):

You can use Memo in functional component, if you want that component should not re-render if props are not updated. Below is the sample code for component **Item** which only re-renders when props changes.

```
const Item = React.memo(function Item({ item }) {
  const rendered = React.useRef(0);
  rendered.current++;
  return (
    <li>
      {item.id} - rendred {rendered.current} times
    </li>
  );
});
```

You can use in component like below:

```
const App = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([]);
  const addItem = () =>
    setItems((items) => [{ id: id() }, ...items]);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={addItem}>+</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        {items.map((item) => (
          <Item key={item.id} item={item} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```